# Getting a Page of DTO objects from Spring Data repository

Tags: spring, spring-data, dto

I'm trying to use DTOs in a Spring project to decouple business and presentation but I'm having problems while retrieving data from the Spring Data repository. Here I have a sample code:

```
public Page<UserDto> findAll(int pageIndex) {
    return userRepository.findAll(createPageable(pageIndex)); // Page<User>
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to return a page of UserDto but I'm getting a page of User.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```
public Page<UserDto> findAll(Pageable p) {
    Page<User> page = userRepository.findAll(p); // Page<User>
    return new PageImpl<UserDto>(UserConverter.convert(page.getContent()), p, page.getTotalElements());
}
```

Comment: But what if  the DTO returned is a compilation of information of  different tables, at that case do you need to do a extra call to the database?

Answer (score 9):

Since Spring-Data 1.10 you can use the `Page#map` function:

```
public Page<UserDto> findAll(Pageable p) {
    return userRepository.findAll(p).map(UserConverter::convert);
}
```

See [Spring Data](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html#map-java.util.function.Function-). The `UserConverter#convert` method takes a `Person` and converts it to `PersonDto`.

```
public PersonDto convert(Person person) {
    return new PersonDto(person.getXyz1(), person.getXyz2);
}
```

Comment: That`s the best answer. With PageImpl<> you can lose page information, such as number of pages, if that page is the last and so on...
I also recommend mapstruct to convert entity to entityDTO.

Comment: Nice answer. Easy to understand and implement.

Answer (score 4):

```
public Page<PersonDto> findAllPageableOrderBylastName(Pageable pageable) {
        Page<Person> personPage = personRepository.findAllByLastNameIsNotNullOrderByLastName(pageable);
        int totalElements = (int) personPage.getTotalElements();
        return new PageImpl<PersonDto>(personPage.getContents()
                .stream()
                .map(person -> new PersonDto(
                        person.getId(),
                        person.getFirstName(),
                        person.getLastName(),
                        person.getNumberMobil(),
                        person.getPresentPosition()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()), pageable, totalElements);
        }
```

I just started programming. I realized so. Working. :)

Comment: What is this `PageImpl`? I have this same situation and I want to set the same approach.

Comment: Should be: return new PageImpl<PersonDto>(personPage.getContents().stream() ...