# How to create Page<> object by using another Page on Java?

Tags: java, arrays, spring, spring-data

I am using jpa paging and getting Page object but I want to return another type of Page object to front end after making some operations on SkcDto. I already have operations which creates IQRecordResultDTO array from the SkcDto

```
private IQRecordResultDTO[] generateIQRecords(List<SkcDTO> iqList) {

//Some operations

return iQRecordResultDTO[];
}
```

And here is the code which calls the above conversion code:

```java
public Page<SkcDTO> generateIQRecordsPage(Query query, Pageable pageable) {
    Page<SkcDTO> skcDTOPage = skcService.iqRecordsByCriteriaAsPage(query, pageable);

    List<SkcDTO> skcList = skcDTOPage.getContent();

    IQRecordResultDTO[] resultArray = generateIQRecords(skcList);

    //HERE IS WHAT I WANT AND NEED TO BE CHANGE I THINK. OR JUST SET NEW CONTENT[] AND ALL OTHER STUFF WILL BE SAME LIKE PAGENUMBER, TOTAL ELEMENT ETC.
    Page<IQRecordResultDTO> iqResultPage = skcDTOPage.map(skc -> {
        IQRecordResultDTO resultDto = convertSkcToIQResultDTO(skc);
        return resultDto;
    });

    return skcDTOPage;
}
```

I already have Page succesfully but if I apply pagination to this page then I do pagination on another page and result is becoming wrong. So I just want to return correct type of Page object, everything will be same (page number, totalPage, totalElement etc) but the *content[]* of the object will be set to another type.

I could not find something like "just copy the Page including all elements except *content[]* of it"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a Page of DTO objects from Spring Data repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27557240/getting-a-page-of-dto-objects-from-spring-data-repository)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
Page<IQRecordResultDTO> iqResultPage = new PageImpl<IQRecordResultDTO>(
                Arrays.asList(generateIQRecords(skcDTOPage.getContent())), 
                skcDTOPage.getPageable(),
                skcDTOPage.getTotalElements()
);
```

Comment: cheers :), It was straight forward.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if I understand what you want to ask actually because it seems that you already figured it out based on the codes from your question...

So consider that you already has `Page<SkcDTO>` , and you want to convert it to `Page<IQRecordResultDTO>` . You first need to have a function to define how to convert one `SkcDTO` to one `IQRecordResultDTO` :

```java
public IQRecordResultDTO toIQRecordResultDTO(SkcDTO skc){
    
}
```

Then you can simply use `Page.map()` to convert it :

```java
Page<SkcDTO> skcPage = .........
Page<IQRecordResultDTO> result = skcPage.map(skc->toIQRecordResultDTO(skc));
```

Comment: I was stuck with the same problem and your answer helped me to move forward! Thanks!

Comment: In my case, I have simplified the code to:

public Page<FooDTO> findAll(Pageable page) {
      return this.fooRepository.findAll(page).map( foo -> new FooDTOMapper(foo));
}